# Qual è il senso di "spaiato" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Rosso al pari di una Bugatti, ma di meno nobile stirpe
>   e tenuto su col respiro, il *cabriolet* dai parafanghi **spaiati** in cui l’attesi alla fermata della Cuba, la mattina del giorno previsto.

Ho cercato il verbo "spaiare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non sono sicura di aver capito il senso di "parafanghi spaiati" nel contesto del passaggio sopra citato. Significa che alla cabriolet mancava qualche parafango?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaiato nel contesto da te citato significa che i parafanghi non erano uguali (come dovrebbe essere normalmente su un'auto) erano di diverso tipo e non che ne mancava qualcuno.

Il significato adatto su Treccani per [spaiare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spaiare/) è il seguente:

> ◆ Part. pass. ***spaiato***, anche come agg.: *calze, scarpe, pantofole
>   spaiate*, che mancano della compagna, o **che appartengono ciascuna a
>   paia diverse.**

Cosa peraltro probabile su una macchina che era "tenuta su col respiro", cioè in condizioni precarie.

Comment: Grazie: non capivo neanche il senso dell'espressione "tenuta su col respiro".